# TCP connection between client and server gone wrong

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp

I establish a TCP connection between my server and client which runs on the same host. We gather and read from the server or say source in our case continuously.
We read data on say 3 different ports.

Once the source stops publishing data or gets restarted , the server/source is not able to publish data again on the same port saying port is already bind. The reason given is that client still has established connection on those ports.

I wanted to know what could be the probable reasons of this ? Can there be issue since client is already listening on these ports and trying to reconnect again and again because we try this reconnection mechanism. I am more looking for reason on source side as the same code in client sides when source and client are on different host and not the same host works perfectly fine for us.

Edit:- 
I found this while going through various article .

> On the question of using SO_LINGER to send a RST on close to avoid the TIME_WAIT state: I've been having some problems with router access servers (names withheld to protect the guilty) that have problems dealing with back-to-back connections on a modem dedicated to a specific channel. What they do is let go of the connection, accept another call, attempt to connect to a well-known socket on a host, and the host refuses the connection because there is a connection in TIME_WAIT state involving the well-known socket. (Stevens' book *TCP Illustrated,* Vol 1 discusses this problem in more detail.) In order to avoid the connection-refused problem, I've had to install an option to do reset-on-close in the server when the server initiates the disconnection.

Link to source:- http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2941

I guess i am facing the same problem: 'attempt to connect to a well-known socket on a host, and the host refuses the connection'. Probable fix mention is 'option to do reset-on-close in the server when the server initiates the disconnection'. Now how do I do that ?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on the server socket before you bind it and call `listen().`

**EDIT** The suggestion to fiddle around with `SO_LINGER` option is worthless and dangerous to your data in flight. Just use `SO_RESUSEADDR.`

Comment: Edited my question giving exact scenario i am facing . Will your answer still hold true for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the socket bound to that port before you restart/shutdown the server!

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html

Also, there's a timeout time, which I think is 4 minutes, so if you created a TCP socket and close it, you may still have to wait 4 minutes until it closes.

You can use netstat to see all the bound ports on your system.  If you shut down your server, or close your server after forking on connect, you may have zombie processes which are bound to certain ports that do not close and remain active, and thus, you can't rebind to the same port.  Show some code.

Comment: netstat shows the client connection is still there , but i am not sure if its connection from client side or its due to improper way in which server got down without closing the socket . Problem is when client process is shut then server is able to again publish on those ports.

Comment: How are you closing the socket on the server?  What is happening, is I believe the server socket  isn't sending the close hand shake of the TCP connection, and your client is still consuming that socket OR, the socket remains open since you're not closing it on the server (and its stuck in a zombie process).  Make sure to call shutdown with a value of 2 in the how instead of close to ensure the socket is shutdown completely (without waiting for transmission). http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html

Comment: You don't need to close a socket before exiting the process that owns it. Linux will do that for you, including the close handshake. Adding a shutdown won't change the behaviour. Your link doesn't say otherwise.

Comment: -You don't need to close a socket before exiting the process that owns it.  If you fork you do.